# Entering dependent answer in SPSS

Tags: spss

How should I enter data for questionnaire in SPSS where respondent answer to question number 10 only if they answer qno.8 as yes else they answer question no. 9 and skip 8.
For example:

> ```
> 8. Have you ever tried online shopping?(IF yes go to Q 9 else to Q 10)
> 1. yes
> 2. No
> 9. If yes, What is the reason
> 1.
> 2.
> 10. If no, What is the reason
> 1.
> 2.
> ```

If I enter value in 9 i get 10 as missing data in Cross tab generation

Answer (score 0):

SPSS can have multiple types of missing values, and here is an instance in which I would use them. For example, the below value labels plus missing values command would give labels describing whether the missing data is due to the skip pattern or due to an actual missing.

```
value labels Q8 Q9 Q10
1 'Yes'
2 'No'
8 'Skip'
9 'Missing'.
missing values Q9 Q10 (8,9).
```

Note even if 9 and 10 are string values, you can still define certain strings to be missing. If you want all categories to be displayed in `CROSSTABS`, see integer mode and the `MISSING` subcommand.